# Passing Value from UIViewController to UIView - coming <null> always

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have `UIViewController` i.e `XXX.h` and `.m`.

`@property(atomic,retain) id dPgmDetails; //(View Controller)`

I have `UIView` `yyy.h` and `.m` on above `UIViewController`.

```
@property(atomic,retain) id dJson;
```

I tried to send json response as `id`  from view controller to view like below...

`yyy(view Object).dJson = dPgmDetails; //(view)`

But its working between view controllers, not between view controller to view. So kindly suggest me the solution! thanks in advance.

Comment: Post your .h files of `UIViewController` and `UIView`. With so less information I don't think somebody can help you solving your problem

Answer (score 0):

I think u forgot to  synthesize

```
  UIView , yyy.h
  @property(nonatomic,retain) id dJson; //put nonatomic

 //yyy.m file
 @synthesize dJson; //synthesize it 



//in XXX.m
(view object).dJson =  dPgmDetails;
```

hope this helps :)

Comment: No Shan! I synthesized! But still giving null :(.

Comment: Hey ! I solved this by sending values via init Method , But still the above method is not working :(